# Function types as MonadReader

Tags: haskell

I'm going through the `lens` [tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-tutorial-1.0.3/docs/Control-Lens-Tutorial.html) and, in particular, trying to wrap my head around the types involved in `view`.

So, taking the definitions

```
data Atom = Atom { _element :: String, _point :: Point }
data Point = Point { _x :: Double, _y :: Double }
makeLenses ''Atom
makeLenses ''Point
```

let's inspect the type of the expression `view (point . x)`:

```
*Main> :t view (point . x)
view (point . x) :: MonadReader Atom m => m Double
```

So, given an environment with an `Atom` we can produce a `Double` wrapped in a `MonadReader`. Nice, that's even more generic than a lens newbie could expect!

Now, let's try to apply this to some `atom`:

```
*Main> :t view (point . x) (Atom "C" (Point 1 2))
view (point . x) (Atom "C" (Point 1 2)) :: Double
```

How does this type-check given the above type for `view (point . x)`? I know there is an instance of `MonadReader` for the partially applied function type `r ->`, but how is ghc able to figure out that this particular instance shall be used in this case (if that's the one that's indeed used, of course)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key point is that you used the syntax for *application*.

When you write

```
view (point . x) (Atom "C" (Point 1 2))
```

you are essentially writing the application `f a` where `f = view (point . x)` and `a = Atom "C" (Point 1 2)`. To type check `f a` GHC initially starts from

```
f :: t1 -> t2     -- in prefix for rm, this is written as (->) t1 t2
a :: t1
```

for some fresh type variables `t1, t2`. This is always done for all applications.
(Well, almost. Some advanced types require a more careful algorithm, but I'll neglect that.)

However, GHC also knows

```
f :: MonadReader Atom m => m Double
a :: Atom
```

so it deduces `t1 ~ Atom` and `m ~ (->) t1 ~ (->) Atom`. Since this is indeed a `MonadRead Atom` instance, it proceeds with that.